# Detect bad air quality because of burned firewood

Tags: smart-home, sensors

In my neighbourhood people burn a lot of firewood. I always deactivate my automatic ventilation when I smell it, but I would like to have something better.

Are there sensors to detect this?

Comment: yes, there are sensors available... not an IoT question

Comment: I think implicitly it is an IoT question, since the OP is clearly looking for an electronic sensor that can be used to either automatically deactivate their ventilation or to send a message to allow them to do it before they can detect it by smell.

Comment: It would be best to include details about what exactly your goal is with this project; what system you want to hook this sensor into, and what systems you already have in place. This will give a better idea as to what your requirements are for the sensor. Furthermore, telling us what research you have done so far will help us enormously. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for a 'particulate' or 'particle' sensor,  which will be characterised by the particle size it detects, e.g. PM10 (10 micron) which can be generated by burning. See [here](https://ww2.arb.ca.gov/resources/inhalable-particulate-matter-and-health) for information on particle sizes.

Answer (score 3):

You could try **MQ135** and tune it to detect the smoke. It has a potentiometer that changes its sensitivity to CO2. Move it around and tune it to trigger when certain smoke density is present.
you could use it with esp8266 or esp32 as it's cheap, performant and resilient of course if you buy from a reliable source. that's your project there

ESP8266/ESP32
MQ135
Some wires or PCB if you can
5v source / old phone charger and you are good to go
you could find ready to use code example